# Best iPhone SSH App?

Tags: ssh, iphone, application

I have been googling the subject for awhile and all I'm finding is reviews of apps from 2008. I'm sure these apps have changed in the last few years. Before I go out and buy all the apps suggested, does anyone have a recommendation on the best SSH client for the iphone?

The main ones I'm seeing are:

```
-iSSH (which I bought and its very hard to use... small keys, etc)
-Prompt
-TouchTerm
-pTerm
-SSH
```

This may not be the right place to ask this, please point me in the right direction if its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just switched from iSSH to Prompt. Universal app, autocomplete, nice interaction design from the Panic team (who brought us Transmit, Coda...), and regular updates make it a winner for me.

Comment: I went ahead and purchased Prompt. So far it is a much better experience than iSSH. Thanks for your help.